# Recent updated version of `@types/node` is creating an error. The previous version was working fine

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I'm getting this error

```
error TS2694: Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Global'.
4 interface CustomNodeJsGlobal extends NodeJS.Global
```

While running this

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

// add prisma to the NodeJS global type
interface CustomNodeJsGlobal extends NodeJS.Global {
  prisma: PrismaClient;
}

// Prevent multiple instances of Prisma Client in development
declare const global: CustomNodeJsGlobal;

const prisma = global.prisma || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") global.prisma = prisma;

export default prisma;
```

**IT'S THE PROBLEM WITH `@types/node` VERSION.**
--> With `"@types/node": "^15.4.0"` (i don't remember precisely but it started from 15 (15.x.x))
--> The error is shown after updating to the latest version `"@types/node": "^16.3.0"`

**What is the standard way to make it work with the latest version `"@types/node": "^16.3.0",` ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of `node@16` the `NodeJS.Global` interface [has been removed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/53669) in favor of [`globalThis`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis).

You can declare new global variable in a module file as:

```ts
declare global {
  var NEW_GLOBAL: string;
}
```

And in a non-module file (no top-level import/export) as:

```ts
declare var NEW_GLOBAL: string;
```

**Important note: variable must be declared as `var`. `let` or `const` variables doesn't show up on `globalThis`**.

So, your code may be rewritten as:

```ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient;
}

const prisma = global.prisma || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") global.prisma = prisma;

export default prisma;
```

Comment: Be sure to read the bold letter, I didn't and lost like 3 hours 